# Pandas groupby and sum if column contains substring

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add two additional rows to a data frame, each row sums the matches in the 'Type' column, I want the first column to search for the string 'car' in Type and the second for 'truck'. In excel I'd use a SUMIF function, is it possible to do with pandas and groupby or another method?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Type': ['red car','blue car','yellow car', 'red truck', 'blue truck', 'yellow truck'], 
    'California':[3,10,9,1,9,4],
    'New York':[1,6,1,10,7,10],
    'Georgia':[3,3,8,6,9,1]
})

cars = df['Type'].str.contains('car', case=False, na=False).sum() #as far as I've got
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.concat([df,
           df.groupby(df['Type'].str.split(' ').str[-1]).sum().reset_index()],
          ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
           Type  California  New York  Georgia
0       red car           3         1        3
1      blue car          10         6        3
2    yellow car           9         1        8
3     red truck           1        10        6
4    blue truck           9         7        9
5  yellow truck           4        10        1
6           car          22         8       14
7         truck          14        27       16
```

***Details:***

You can use `.str` accessor to `split` your Type into two parts color and vehicle, then slice that list and get the last value, vehicle, with `.str[-1]`.  Use this vehicle series to `groupby` your dataframe and `sum`.  Lastly, `pd.concat` the results of the groupby sum with your original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Somethin' like that:

```
# create a group col com 'car' and 'truck' values
df['group'] = df.Type.apply(lambda x: x.split()[1]) 

# grouping them values in a new df     
df_group = df.groupby('group',as_index=False)[['California', 'New York', 
                                     'Georgia']].sum().rename(columns={
    'group': 'Type'})

# concat both df and df_group
df_result = pd.concat([df, df2]).drop('group', axis=1).set_index('Type')

df_result:
              California  New York  Georgia
Type                                       
red car                3         1        3
blue car              10         6        3
yellow car             9         1        8
red truck              1        10        6
blue truck             9         7        9
yellow truck           4        10        1
car                   22         8       14
truck                 14        27       16
```

I hope this snippet help you

Comment: Nearly the same solution as I proposed.